# Jacoco intstrumentation 'Missing @CsvField annotation on field'

Tags: java, teamcity, jacoco, jsefa

I am trying to use the Jacoco code coverage analyzer plugin for TeamCity CI tool, however there are some Classes that fail when being instrumented by Jacoco causing the error:

`java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Missing @CsvField annotation on field com.myApp.MyClass.$jacocoData`

I am using JSefa library for serializing objects to csv, I have tests that cover the serialization, however when trying to run the tests with the Jacoco coverage runner I get the mentioned error, it is complaining about a field with name jacocoData that should be created by the Jacoco instrumentation.

I know that I can skip those classes from being instrumented, but that is not something I want because I will lose the coverage metrics on them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you mean by "Apache JSefa": can't find project in Apache Software Foundation with such name, able to find a quite old http://jsefa.sourceforge.net/ , but it doesn't belong to Apache Software Foundation even those it uses an Apache license.

In any case most likely you're facing what is described in [JaCoCo FAQ](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html) as

> #### My code uses reflection. Why does it fail when I execute it with JaCoCo?
>
> To collect execution data JaCoCo instruments the classes under test which adds two members to the classes: A private static field $jacocoData and a private static method $jacocoInit(). Both members are marked as synthetic.
>
> Please change your code to ignore synthetic members. This is a good practice anyways as also the Java compiler creates synthetic members in certain situation.

i.e. library to which your refer to as "JSefa" doesn't ignore synthetic fields, while should.

So there is not much options:

- either library should be fixed. Check the version of library - maybe you're using an old version and this is already fixed in a newer? If not fixed, then report problem to the vendor of library.
- or do not use this library / use another library to do the same
- or classes should be excluded from computation of code coverage

Comment: You are right, JSefa is not an Apache project, I am updating the question accordingly